# How to create a lazy-seq generating, anonymous recursive function in Clojure?

Tags: binding, recursion, clojure, combinators, lazy-sequences

**Edit**: I discovered a partial answer to my own question in the process of writing this, but I think it can easily be improved upon so I will post it anyway. Maybe there's a better solution out there?

I am looking for an easy way to define recursive functions in a `let` form without resorting to `letfn`. This is probably an unreasonable request, but the reason I am looking for this technique is because I have a mix of data and recursive functions that depend on each other in a way requires a lot of nested `let` and `letfn` statements.

I wanted to write the recursive functions that generate lazy sequences like this (using the Fibonacci sequence as an example):

```
(let [fibs (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fibs (rest fibs)))]
  (take 10 fibs))
```

But it seems in clojure that `fibs` cannot use it's own symbol during binding. The obvious way around it is using `letfn`

```
(letfn [(fibo [] (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + (fibo) (rest (fibo)))))]
  (take 10 (fibo)))
```

But as I said earlier this leads to a lot of cumbersome nesting and alternating `let` and `letfn`.

To do this without `letfn` and using just `let`, I started by writing something that uses what I think is the U-combinator (just heard of the concept today):

```
(let [fibs (fn [fi] (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + (fi fi) (rest (fi fi)))))]
  (take 10 (fibs fibs)))
```

But how to get rid of the redundance of `(fi fi)`?

It was at this point when I discovered the answer to my own question after an hour of struggling and incrementally adding bits to the combinator Q.

```
(let [Q (fn [r] ((fn [f] (f f)) (fn [y] (r (fn [] (y y))))))
      fibs (Q (fn [fi] (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + (fi) (rest (fi))))))]
  (take 10 fibs))
```

What is this `Q` combinator called that I am using to define a recursive sequence? It looks like the Y combinator with no arguments `x`. Is it the same?

```
(defn Y [r] 
  ((fn [f] (f f)) 
   (fn [y] (r (fn [x] ((y y) x))))))
```

Is there another function in clojure.core or clojure.contrib that provides the functionality of Y or Q? I can't imagine what I just did was idiomatic...

Comment: I noticed that writing fibs in this way results in terrible performance because (I presume) the combinator doesn't store results under the symbol fibs, but rather re-generates values on the fly? How can I make this more performant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### letrec

I have written a `letrec` macro for Clojure recently, here's [a Gist of it](http://gist.github.com/486880). It acts like Scheme's `letrec` (if you happen to know that), meaning that it's a cross between `let` and `letfn`: you can bind a set of names to mutually recursive values, without the need for those values to be functions (lazy sequences are ok too), as long as it is possible to evaluate the head of each item without referring to the others (that's Haskell -- or perhaps type-theoretic -- parlance; "head" here might stand e.g. for the lazy sequence object itself, with -- crucially! -- no forcing involved).

You can use it to write things like

```
(letrec [fibs (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fibs (rest fibs)))]
  fibs)
```

which is normally only possible at top level. See the Gist for more examples.

As pointed out in the question text, the above could be replaced with

```
(letfn [(fibs [] (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + (fibs) (rest (fibs)))))]
  (fibs))
```

for the same result *in exponential time*; the `letrec` version has linear complexity (as does a top-level `(def fibs (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fibs (rest fibs))))` form).

### iterate

Self-recursive seqs can often be constructed with `iterate` -- namely when a fixed range of look-behind suffices to compute any given element. See `clojure.contrib.lazy-seqs` for an example of how to compute `fibs` with `iterate`.

### clojure.contrib.seq

`c.c.seq` provides an interesting function called `rec-seq`, enabling things like

```
(take 10 (cseq/rec-seq fibs (map + fibs (rest fibs))))
```

It has the limitation of only allowing one to construct a single self-recursive sequence, but it might be possible to lift from it's source some implementation ideas enabling more diverse scenarios. If a single self-recursive sequence not defined at top level is what you're after, this has to be the idiomatic solution.

### combinators

As for combinators such as those displayed in the question text, it is important to note that they are hampered by the lack of TCO (tail call optimisation) on the JVM (and thus in Clojure, which elects to use the JVM's calling conventions directly for top performance).

### top level

There's also the option of putting the mutually recursive "things" at top level, possibly in their own namespace. This doesn't work so great if those "things" need to be parameterised somehow, but namespaces can be created dynamically if need be (see `clojure.contrib.with-ns` for implementation ideas).

### final comments

I'll readily admit that the `letrec` thing is far from idiomatic Clojure and I'd avoid using it in production code if anything else would do (and since there's always the top level option...). However, it is (IMO!) nice to play with and it appears to work well enough. I'm personally interested in finding out how much can be accomplished without `letrec` and to what degree a `letrec` macro makes things easier / cleaner... I haven't formed an opinion on that yet. So, here it is. Once again, for the single self-recursive seq case, `iterate` or contrib might be the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! I'm aware of iterate but it is hard to use in my particular problem (because the real structure of the problem uses data from multiple irregularly shaped trees, not a simple Fibonacci). I will definitely study that macro and rec-seq though!

Comment: Why is `letrec` *far from idiomatic*? It just does for `def`s what `letfn` does for `defn`s: enables self and mutual reference at a local level. If we were prepared to forego rebinding - typically `(loop [v v])` - `let` could work this way. No?

Comment: It's not idiomatic because it's not something you'd encounter in Clojure code in the wild, my implementation from four years ago notwithstanding. It's not particularly surprising -- for one thing, the way the macro works is different to the way in which a built-in implementation would, so it is somewhat alien to the language; and then it's not something that's *needed* all that often. This is not a slight to `letrec`'s usefulness, just a statement of fact about Clojure coding practices.

Comment: As a side note, [here](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/3c6b34b8db36e64b85c0)'s a gist of a newer version that I wrote a long time ago, but never got round to publishing anywhere. It avoids the need to do its own code walking through the use of tools.macro's `symbol-macrolet`, so I'd be more comfortable using it.

Answer (score 8):

`fn` takes an optional name argument with that name bound to the function in its body.  Using this feature, you could write `fibs` as:

```
(def fibs ((fn generator [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (generator b (+ a b))))) 0 1))
```

Comment: Nice catch! I forgot about that one.