# Is it possible to create circular references in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, circular-reference

Ignoring native interop and transients, is it possible to create any data structures in Clojure that contain direct circular references ?

It would seem that immutable data structures can only ever contain references to previous versions of themselves. Are there any Clojure APIs that could create a new data structure that has a reference to itself ?

Scheme has the letrec form which allows mutually recursive structures to be created - but, as far as I can tell, Clojure does not have anything similar.

This question is related to porting Clojure to iOS - which does not have garbage collection, but does have reference counting.

Comment: Here's a closely related SO question: [How to create a lazy-seq generating, anonymous recursive function in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373157/how-to-create-a-lazy-seq-generating-anonymous-recursive-function-in-clojure). See my answer to it for a number of possible approaches. One of them is through a `letrec` macro of some sort -- see [this Gist](http://gist.github.com/486880) for my version (which works like Scheme's `letrec`).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It appears that I will need full GC to handle Clojure and I'm experimenting with Gambit Scheme as the translation target.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a circular reference very easily by putting some form of reference inside a data structure, then updating the reference to point back to the overall structure.

A trivial example:

```
(def a [(atom nil)])

(reset! (first a) a)
```

This will create a list with one element, which is an atom that points back at the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would only ever use a ref type as a top level object, so I never considered this.

Comment: is this a var that points to a list that points to an atom that references a var

Comment: @Arther - technically it is a var that points at a vector that contains an atom that points at the vector. i.e. The var itself isn't in the circular loop.

Comment: This example results in StackOverflowError in my environment:(

Answer (score 8):

In Clojure most circular data structures will explicitely go through a ref type of some kind (eg atom).

However you can create a circular sequence (it's somewhat an oxymoron):

```
(let [a (atom nil)] (reset! a (lazy-seq (cons 1 @a))))
```

And since Clojure 1.2 with deftype you can create other datatypes which can introduce circularity without using explicitely (from the usercode at least) any kind of ref type.