# Is there any way to reffer to a struct-map entry previously defined (inline)?

Tags: clojure

The title is not that great, but it is difficult to find a good one-liner :)

The question is the following. Given the declaration:

```
(def mystruct (create-struct :a :b :c))
```

is it possible to build an instance the following way (something similar, obviously):

```
(struct-map mystruct :a 1 :b 2 :c (inc (:b this)))
```

I managed to get something like this in the following bizzaro way:

```
(def mystructinst (struct-map mystruct :a 1 :b 2 :c (inc (:b mystructinst))))
```

But to be honest, I don't know why that worked. I thought mystructinst is only bound *after* the evaluation of the contained forms. Is this a clean way of performing this task? Is there any better one?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Same wavelength: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651420/advice-discussion-on-anonymous-self-referential-data-structures

Comment: @OmriBernstein thank you, that's a great link and it sure is the same thing as what I was trying to achieve. However, I'm left to wonder about why the construct I proposed works.

Comment: @TudorVintilescu: Your last code doesn't work (throws null pointer ex). It may have worked in your case because while trying things out you have already defined a `mystructinst`

Comment: BTW, struct-maps are quasi-deprecated now in favor of records. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/pnDl4OgzqBM/zjDioSsxkvEJ

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
(let [b 2] (struct-map mystruct :a 1 :b b :c (inc b)))
```

You are correct that the symbol is bound only *after* the evaluation of the contained forms when using `def`, which is why your last example throws a NullPointerException. You probably predefined mystructinst somewhere else without realizing it. You can move the variable you want to reference outside the `struct-map` and put it in a `let` instead. Then, it'll be accessible anywhere.

Also, note that `let` *does* allow you to refer to previous bindings in subsequent ones:

```
user=> (let [a 1 b (inc a)] b)
2
```